# How to Create Multiple Stacks?

Tags: perl, stack, singly-linked-list

Perl Help

I have a complicated utility program (let's call it KIP for short) that
I'm converting from AWK to perl. AWK had a facility for a doubly linked
list which I used.  This worked great, but I can't figure out how to do
this in perl. I know that a FIFO linked list is a good solution.

KIP Function (If you are interested)
KIP removes duplicate items from a document.  The way the AWK program
works is that it scans the document looking for duplicate items and
builds an array showing the "real" items and all of its duplicates.  I
need a FIFO linked list to the duplicates as shown here:

```
                 PICTORIAL OF THE FUNCTION
REAL
ITEM    ARRAY OF $POINTER[]                   LINKED LIST
NUMBER
      +-------------+---------+   +---------------+   +---------------+
 1    | real item 1 | ------> |   |dup_1_of_item_1|-->|dup_n_of_item_1|
      +-------------+---------+   +---------------+   +---------------+

      +-------------+---------+   +---------------+   +---------------+
 2    | real item 2 | ------> |   |dup_1_of_item_2|-->|dup_n_of_item_2|
      +-------------+---------+   +---------------+   +---------------+

      +-------------+---------+   +---------------+   +---------------+
 3    | real item 3 | ------> |   |dup_1_of_item_3|-->|dup_n_of_item_3|
      +-------------+---------+   +---------------+   +---------------+
               ...                             ...
```

KIP will run the "real item n" array to process each real item.  To do
so, KIP will run the linked list chain to remove the duplicate items
from the document.  It would be nice just to push the duplicates of
"real item 1" onto a stack and save the stack address for later. Then,
later, KIP could access the saved stack address and pop the items off.

I know it is my lack of knowledge of perl, but I'm having a hard time
implementing such an array-of-pointer structure.  I think push and pop
should work, but either the syntax is wrong or it just doesn't work for
me.

Here's what I'm finding hard -

1. I need to create dynamic stacks that I can push information onto.
2. The stacks will be accessed in different sections of KIP so I need
   to save the stack address in an array for later.
3. The stack is dynamically built (not an array built using QW which
   all documentation seems to describe).
4. I need numerous stacks (one for each real_item for which there is a
   duplicate).

Can someone give me direction?  Any pertinent information will be
appreciated.

TIA

HERE'S WHAT I'VE DONE;

```
ADD ITEMS TO STACK
   # $IDX_ori_iSub - subscript for the real item
   # $IDX_dup_iSub - subscript for each duplicate item that is
   #                 found

   # populate the fields for the stack
    $MsgID      =  $IDXMsgID[$IDX_dup_iSub];
    $LineNumber =  $IDXLineNumber[$IDX_dup_iSub];
    $Offset     =  $IDXOffset[$IDX_dup_iSub];
    $LineCount  =  $IDXLineCount[$IDX_dup_iSub];
    $KCount     =  $IDXKCount[$IDX_dup_iSub];

   # set up stack
    my @stackOfDuplicates;

   # Save the address of the stack for later access
    if ( $IDXChain[$IDX_ori_iSub] == 0)
    {
        $IDXChain[$IDX_ori_iSub] = \@stackOfDuplicates;
    }

   # Push items onto list.
    push @stackOfDuplicates, $MsgID      ;
    push @stackOfDuplicates, $LineNumber ;
    push @stackOfDuplicates, $Offset     ;
    push @stackOfDuplicates, $LineCount  ;
    push @stackOfDuplicates, $KCount     ;
```

REMOVE ITEMS FROM STACK

```
    my @stackOfDuplicates = $IDXChain[$IDX_iSub];
    if ( @stackOfDuplicates )
    {
       # Remove first items from list.
        my $MsgID      = shift @stackOfDuplicates;
        my $LineNumber = shift @stackOfDuplicates;
        my $Offset     = shift @stackOfDuplicates;
        my $LineCount  = shift @stackOfDuplicates;
        my $KCount     = shift @stackOfDuplicates;

print "  \$MsgID = $MsgID";
print "  \$LineNumber = $LineNumber";
print "  \$Offset = $Offset";
print "  \$LineCount = $LineCount";
print "  \$KCount = $KCount";
    }
```

TYPICAL OF THE RESULTS I'VE SEEN THUS FAR

```
  $MsgID = ARRAY(0x2b786c0)
Use of uninitialized value $LineNumber in concatenation (.) or string
  $LineNumber =
Use of uninitialized value $Offset in concatenation (.) or string at
  $Offset =
Use of uninitialized value $LineCount in concatenation (.) or string
  $LineCount =
Use of uninitialized value $KCount in concatenation (.) or string at
  $KCount =
```

Comment: To summarize, you're trying to remove duplicate records from a text file?

Comment: In Perl, you use hashes (associative arrays, in which the keys are strings) for this sort of thing, not arrays (indexed with integers) or linked lists. Arrays are just clumsy most of the time. Linked lists can be useful, and they can be built using hashes, but I wouldn't use them here.

Comment: Always start your Perl scripts with `use strict; use warnings;` so you get proper compile-time error reporting.

Comment: See the updated post which I think identifies the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of restoring the stack of duplicates in preparation for removal, the address ends up entered as its first element.  Then the print at the end gets the first variable being the array reference, and since this was the only thing under `@stackOfDuplicates` the other variables don't get anything (ending up `undef`), and the `Use of unitialized ...` is printed.

Assigning a reference to an array in Perl does not restore the array (associated with that reference), it is not a pointer assignment to the first array address like it would be in C. Instead, at that point a new array is created and that reference is made its first element.

To obtain an array from its reference we need to de-reference it

```
my @stackOfDuplicates = @{ $IDXChain[$IDX_iSub] };
```

Or, possibly more clearly

```
my $ref_stackOfDuplicates = $IDXChain[$IDX_iSub];
my @stackOfDuplicates = @$ref_stackOfDuplicates;
```

I don't see anything wrong with your data structures. In Perl `FIFO` is indeed implemented by array and `push`+`shift` (or `push`+`pop` for stack).

Comment: Please read [answer] to learn what makes a good answer on [so]. Answering an unclear question with a speculative answer doesn't benefit anyone.

Comment: Yes, because the question still isn't any good. At best, it's a poorly-written and unclear question that doesn't contain a [mcve]. At worst, it's a duplicate of any one of a number of "How do I dereference an array reference?" questions.

Comment: @MattJacob  Hm, I don't recall seeing recently such a thoroughly written up question.  With the problem statement including ASCII drawing and with code and output.  The error is simple but OP doesn't know that, thus the question.   Thank you, I'll wait some more.  I am removing these comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack of duplicates is really a stack of "details about duplicates".  This is greatly complicating things.  I suspect you would prefer to have a small tweak to fix up what you already have but you would be far better off stepping back, doing a little research and then having a second go.

Critical to the whole operation is to gather the attributes that describe one "duplicate item" or "original item" into an associative array - i.e. a defacto object.  Better still, [Mo.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mo) is a minimalist Perl module that gives you basic objects.

If installing modules is beyond your reach or, if you don't have the admin access to formally install a module, you can just copy [these three lines](https://metacpan.org/source/INGY/Mo-0.39/lib/Mo.pm) and put them in a file called **Mo.pm** *in the same directory as your script* and then you're good to go.

You also need to create another file called **DocItem.pm**, again, *in the same directory* which will define your DocItem class. Put the following in it:

```
package DocItem;
use Mo;

has MsgID      =>  ();
has LineNumber =>  ();
has Offset     =>  ();
has LineCount  =>  ();
has KCount     =>  ();
```

Now you have a class that you can "pull into" your script.  Your code should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use DocItem;

my @stack ;
my @problem ;

# Have to create an "original" and some duplicates by making
# up the attributes that define each item

my $original = DocItem->new(
                  MsgID        =>  "id14" ,
                  LineNumber   =>  126    ,  # All these made up
                  Offset       =>  17     ,
                  LineCount    =>  64     ,
                  KCount       =>  1237   ,
              );

print "MsgID: ",     $original->MsgID, "\n";    #  How you access an attribute
print "LineCount: ", $original->LineCount;
print " ==> ";
$original->LineCount(8600);   #  How you set an attribute after object creation
print $original->LineCount, "\n";

$problem[0] = $original ;     # NOTE: make the DocItem called "$original" the
                              # first item of the array @problem.

# Using a loop to make-up 4 DocItem objects representing 4 duplicates
for (1 .. 4) {
    my $id   = "id" . $_ ;   # All these attributes made up
    my $line = 12 * $_   ;   # values based on the loop variable
    my $off  = 18 + $_   ;
    my $Lcnt = 126 + $_  ;
    my $KC   = 1000 - $_ ;

    # Create a new DocItem representing one duplicate
    my $duplicate = DocItem->new(
                    MsgID        =>  $id   ,
                    LineNumber   =>  $line ,
                    Offset       =>  $off  ,
                    LineCount    =>  $Lcnt ,
                    KCount       =>  $KC   ,
                );

    # NOTE: push the DocItem called "$duplicate" onto the problem array
    # This builds up a structure representing one "horizontal line" of your pic
    push @problem, $duplicate;
}

# The four "pushes" (one for each loop iteration) leaves @problem looking like:

#  $problem[0]     $problem[1]     $problem[2]    $problem[3]    $problem[4]
#  ===========     ===========     ===========    ===========    ===========
#    MsgID:  id14    MsgID:  id1     MsgID:  id2    MsgID:  id3    MsgID:  id4
#    Offset: 17      Offset: 19      Offset: 20     Offset: 21     Offset: 22
#    KCount: 1237    KCount: 999     KCount: 998    KCount: 997    KCount: 996
#    (etc for LineNumber and LineCount)

# Now, push the whole problem array into slot 0 of @stack
push @stack, \@problem;   # Or, $stack[0] = \@problem ;

# In a similar way, build up more arrays representing "problems" each
# with the "original" DocItem in slot 0 and the duplicate DocItems in
# successive slots of the array, and again, push the whole lot onto @stack

# and then....

my $first_problem = shift @stack;
my $first_original = shift @$first_problem;  # Note, this access is required because
                                             # $first_problem holds a reference to an
while (my $dup = shift @$first_problem)  {   # array, not an array;

    # $dup holds one DocItem object representing
    # a duplicate and $first_original holds the
    # DocItem representing the orignal.

    # Do what you need to do

 }
```

Each `@problem` represents one horizontal line in your pic above.  The first slot - `$problem[0]` - holds your original and subsequent duplicates are pushed onto the array.  Then the whole array can be pushed onto `@stack` by taking a reference to your problem array `\@problem`

Then you can iterate over your stack, shift off one whole problem, shift off the original, and then iterate over the duplicates dealing with them.

[Read this](http://perlmaven.com/manipulating-perl-arrays) excellent tutorial by Gabor Szabo to help with keeping "push", "pop", "shift" and "unshift" straight.

Comment: Thanks, but in a 25,000 line program, things are just too fixed to rewrite or start over.  I spent over a week attempting to remove all the HUNDREDS of globals and finally gave up on it.  You are correct, I just needed a tweak.

Comment: I have looked at your code and do understand what you've done.  I need a little more direction in one specific area.  But StackOverflow won't allow me room to ask it.

Comment: Chuck - I'm able to offer you and hour or two of help with it if you want to pursue it -  there are stackoverflow chat rooms.  My timezone is +11hr.  The reason i had nothing to say after you said you couldn't redesign it (which i appreciate it - often its not possible) is that  the existing structure is just too complex to deal with (of course, I've only seen a tiny sample of what you're doing so my opinion has to be seen in that light).

Comment: RE: the program you posted - I have expanded the program to add multiple "problems", but, I cannot make my program work UNLESS I USE DIFFERENT STACKS.  Remember, I build hundreds of stacks before I ever begin to shift the elements off.  So, I now need to dynamically create stack names.  Yes, I know everyone says not to.  Everyone says use a hash.  But, even with a hash, I have the same problem.  Can you tell me how to generate dynamically named arrays?  I've tried variations of this:        $temp = 'problem_' . $control;
\@problem = \@{$temp};
$problem[0] = $original;

Comment: Problems are arrays where each element is a doc_item.
A stack is an array where each element is an array (ie, a problem).
To dynamically create stacks, dynamically create arrays - to do that take a reference to a (lexical) variable.
`for (1 .. 10) { my @tmp = generate_array();  $stacks[$_] = \@tmp }`
But now, the 10 arrays have integer names - each represented by an index in @stacks.
Hence, you need a hash - an array where each index is a text name instead of an integer;

`while (is_more_data($fh)) {  my $name = get_stack_name(); my @tmp = generate_stack($fh); $stacks_hash{ $name } = \@tmp }`